# unable to converting factor to date

Tags: r, date

I have data frame like this:

```
    > a=runif(5)
    > b=c("1-Jan-13", "2-Jan-13", "3-Jan-13", "4-Jan-13", "5-Jan-13")
    > dd = data.frame(a,b)
    > dd 
          a        b
1 0.1873622 1-Jan-13
2 0.1902314 2-Jan-13
3 0.7476141 3-Jan-13
4 0.3584118 4-Jan-13
5 0.2152858 5-Jan-13

    > str(dd)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  0.187 0.19 0.748 0.358 0.215
 $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "1-Jan-13","2-Jan-13",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

I Tried

```
    > dd$b <- as.Date(dd$b, format="%d/%m/%Y")
    > str(dd)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  0.187 0.19 0.748 0.358 0.215
 $ b: Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
```

and

```
 > dd = data.frame(a,b)
 > dd$b <- as.Date(dd$b, format="%d-%m-%Y")
 > str(dd)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  0.187 0.19 0.748 0.358 0.215
 $ b: Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
```

does'n work...

Comment: You need to fix the formats that you are telling R your dates have. Right off the bat, you cannot use `/` since your dates use `-` and you cannot use `%Y` since your years are two digits (so use `%y`); see this http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Comment: ...and I think you need `%b` for the month in your format. See `?strptime`.

Comment: right and the month is wrong, too

Comment: So to clarify `format` refers to the format of the input data, not how you would like the output. You have to reformat the output if you want to display what is returned by `as.Date` in a different format.

Comment: @user3178063 , you are encouraged to write an answer to your own question incorporating the ideas you got in the comments (you may have to wait an hour or so before you're allowed to)

Answer (score 1):

@rawr, @joran and @SimonO'Hanlon are all spot-on. The native R solution would look something like:

```
a <- runif(5)
b <- c("1-Jan-13", "2-Jan-13", "3-Jan-13", "4-Jan-13", "5-Jan-13")
dd <- data.frame(a, b=as.Date(b, format="%d-%b-%y"))
str(dd)
## 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ a: num  0.947 0.997 0.39 0.913 0.178
##  $ b: Date, format: "2013-01-01" ...
```

Where `%b` is the short version of the month name and `%y` indicates year without century.

OR

You could install the spiffy `lubridate` package and use the `ymd()` function which is *really* good at figuring out what format a string is in.

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

dd <- data.frame(a, b=dmy(b))
str(dd)
## 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ a: num  0.947 0.997 0.39 0.913 0.178
##  $ b: POSIXct, format: "2013-01-01" ...
```

As long as whatever you're doing next is cool with a `POSIXct` type vs a `Date` type, you're golden.

As @joran said, tho, it would not hurt to brush up on `?strptime`.

Answer (score -1):

```
> dd
      a        b
1 0.2102705 1-Jan-13
2 0.9018757 2-Jan-13
3 0.4113829 3-Jan-13
4 0.2685403 4-Jan-13
5 0.4664033 5-Jan-13


> str(dd)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ a: num  0.21 0.902 0.411 0.269 0.466
$ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "1-Jan-13","2-Jan-13",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

I changed formats for month from %m to %b and year from %Y to %y and then it works fine.

```
> str(dd)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ a: num  0.21 0.902 0.411 0.269 0.466
$ b: Date, format: "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" ...
```